# Check if last character is [A-Z] or [0-9] SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Anyone know how I can check if the last character of a result is either [A-Z] or [0-9]?

I'm trying to apply to a field called prod_code in my table, values of prod_code are

```
134s
45kfz
78475!
ruj-
```

etc

I only want to extract records by the first 5 characters which have no special characters such as - or ! etc.

I have tried using `(left(prod_code,5),right(prod_code,1) IN ('[0-9]%','[A-Z]%'))`, but that is not working as expected.

Any tips?

Comment: `IN` compares using `=` so yes, that can't work

Comment: Your requirement "*the last character of a result is ...*" contradicts the requirement "*without special characters*" (because that means "anywhere" in the value) and the `left()` or `right()` usage you have. So what exactly is it you are looking for? From the sample data, which ones should be returned?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name some of the prod_codes are 5+ characters. So what I' trying to do is get the first 5 characters of each prod_code and then check if the last character is a special character like ! or -. If they are I will not use. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
where prod_code ~ '^.*[A-Z1-9]$'
```

It is odd you are leaving out `0`.

Comment: this returns an empty result set? is there a comma missing [ A-Z1-9] between z and 1?

Comment: @timz . . . I put the `.` in square braces.  That was not my intention but that is what my fingers typed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below script

```
SELECT regexp_replace(prod_code, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '','g') 
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: when I ran the db crashes and states memory error? My dataset contains over 100,000 records. Even when i limit by 10 it crashes

Comment: @timz: that statement will **not** "crash the db". But with 100,000 rows I'd rather guess it's the SQL _client_ you are using that runs out of memory trying to _display_ that many rows.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name
i guess so, but should it crash even when i limit by 10?